# Fade In/Out of div over slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider with an overlay div i've got it showing on hover, but i would like to make it fade in and fade out

```
  <div>
   <div class="slider-overlay overlay-center">
    <div class="inner hidden">
      <h1 class="text">
        Text
      </h1>
      <hr>
      <p>text</p>
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1">#</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img class="desktop-slide-img" src="image" alt="Let's Do Cocktails">
</div>


   <script>
    $(".slider-overlay").hover(function(){
      $('.inner').removeClass('hidden');
      },function(){
          $('.inner').addClass('hidden');
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: You want to [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)?

Comment: Use .fadeToggle()  instead

Comment: Agreed with both above check here:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/45453529/4248328

Answer (score 1):

You can use fadeIn/fadeOut instead of addClass/removeClass:

```
$(".slider-overlay").hover(function() {
     $('.inner').fadeIn('slow');
  },
  function(){
    $('.inner').fadeOut('slow');
  }
);
```

Also, If you have multiple instance of slider-overlay div, you need to use DOM traversing to traverse to inner element on which hover is being performed. You can use hovered elements context along with `.find()`

```
$('.inner', this).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

Demo here: https://output.jsbin.com/jaqafag

https://jsbin.com/jaqafag/6/edit?html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <div class="slider-overlay overlay-center">
    <div class="inner hidden">
      <h1 class="text">
        Text
      </h1>
      <hr>
      <p>text</p>
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1">#</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img class="desktop-slide-img" src="image" alt="Let's Do Cocktails">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slider-overlay").hover(function(){
       $('.inner').fadeIn("slow");
    }, function(){
       $('.inner').fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```